How can I make particles have trails
I am making a jet animation and am trying to make a countermeasure effect, I have an emitter that emits glowing spheres (flares) and I want these flares to have a smoke trail, I tried doing a smoke sim and I did not like the look of it, there was way to much smoke, I want a thin trail, I tinkered with the settings for a while and still failed to make it look better, I would also not mind just using volumetric particles to do this, but as far as I am aware particles cannot emit particles. How can I add a trail to my particles? Thanks for any help!
